# UWP property changed in dependency property of user control

Tags: mvvm, uwp, dependency-properties

I'm using a user control, binding values from dependency properties.
But the problem is that, when I am trying to change the value, UI doesn't update.
my XAML code in usercontrol :

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Text}" />
```

and C#

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
            }
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Control1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

When I want to use it :

```
        <local:Control text="{Binding Val,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

my ViewModel :

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _val;
    public string Val
    {
        get
        {
            return _val;
        }

        set
        {

            if (_val != value)
            {_val = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Val"));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And when I want to use it in my view and bind it from a view model, property changes does not apply in the user control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `x:bind` default mode is one Time, that you should change the mode to OneWay.

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind Text,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

You shouldn't write the code in  `SetValue(TextProperty, value);` and shouldn't use the Notify in the dependency property for the dependency can auto call changed.

See: [Dependency Properties](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_dependency_properties.htm)